# InvalidRegistration for React Native iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm building React Native App. I have used a [react-native-notification](https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications) library to add the Notification features.

My Andriod app can generate token and received notifications from firebase but for iOS app, the token is generated but when a message is sent to this token id nothing happened instead I am getting an error.

**"error": "InvalidRegistration"**

```
await NotificationsIOS.addEventListener('remoteNotificationsRegistered', onPushRegistered);
  await NotificationsIOS.addEventListener('remoteNotificationsRegistrationFailed', onPushRegistrationFailed);
  await NotificationsIOS.requestPermissions();

function onPushRegistered(deviceToken) {
    // TODO: Send the token to my server so it could send back push notifications...
    console.log("Device Token Received", deviceToken);
  }
```

I used this code to get Device Token on iOS the token is generating but i think it is not a vlaid FCM token. 45f41b17e16b5970fe35.......8222b01289580bae87ba35d2b2bc72b

```
{
  "data": {
    "title": "sample Title",
    "content": "sample text",
    "key": "Im the key"
  },
  "to": "ce4a46370d7c4060b0a4dd.........47de821d0bc1767f124a2fa157afe"
}
```

But when i send the FCM message to this token id it gives me above error. I have also added the APN's certificates to the firebase.
I can generate the local notifications using this library on ios and the remote andriod notification is also working properly. Kindly help me to get it fixed as i don't want to use any other library thanks.

Comment: Are you trying this on an emulator?

Comment: on the real device.